# Date format get changed while saving the record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am developing windows application using MS-ACCESS as back end.

I have table in MS-ACCESS which have Datetime Type Column , which holds today's date.

I have below code. (Code on the form)

```
                Dim oCoupon2 As New Coupon
                oCoupon2.LoadByPK(oCoupon.ID)
                oCoupon2.RedeemedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                oCoupon2.IsRedeemed = "Yes"
                oCoupon2.RedeemedCustomerID = .ID
                Dim isSuccsess As Integer
                isSuccsess = oCoupon2.Save()
```

Code for saving the entity (code in Business Layer)

```
  Public Overrides Function Save() As Boolean
            Try

                Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
                SetColumn(IDColumnName, _ID)
                SetColumn(CouponNoColumnName, _CouponNo)
                SetColumn(ExpDateColumnName, _ExpDate)
                SetColumn(IsRedeemedColumnName, _IsRedeemed)
                SetColumn(RedeemedDateColumnName, _RedeemedDate)
                SetColumn(RedeemedCustomerIDColumnName, _RedeemedCustomerID)
                bSuccess = MyBase.Save()
                ' Ensures that the _DepartmentID is updated with the new Identity value in case of Insert
                If bSuccess Then _ID = MyBase.IdentityColumn
                Return bSuccess

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Function


  Protected Sub SetColumn(ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal Value As Object)
            Try
                If Not _dict.ContainsKey(ColumnName) Then
                    _dict.Add(ColumnName, Value)
                Else
                    If Value Is DBNull.Value Then Value = Nothing
                    _dict(ColumnName) = Value
                End If
            Catch ex As ArgumentException
                ' Exception occurs when adding a key that already exists in dictionary. Try replace mode.
                Try
                    _dict(ColumnName) = Value
                Catch
                    _Error = ex
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception
                _Error = ex
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Sub
```

code in (code at Data Layer)

```
Public Overridable Function Save() As Boolean
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
        If _IsAddNew Then
            bSuccess = Insert()
            If bSuccess Then _IsAddNew = False
        Else
            bSuccess = Update()
        End If
        Return bSuccess
    End Function
```

Its generates following query while saving, in VS 2012

```
UPDATE Coupon SET CouponNo = '262752325',ExpDate = '2/20/2016 00:00:00',IsRedeemed = 'Yes',RedeemedDate = '1/6/2016 20:28:31',RedeemedCustomerID = Null WHERE ID = 17
```

It supposes to save todays data i.e. 1-Jan-16 but while saving the records its get saved as a 1-June-16, Please check below...

[image]

I have checked the time of the my machine it shows the perfect time. i.e. 1-Jan-2016
Which settings I have to check ?

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  Formats are simply how we display them to the users.  If the columns *is* a DateTime type, you should not pass/store a string value (which is apparently what `RedeemedDate` is or else Option Strict is not on).  Access is not showing the raw, stored data but formatting it for you (a user).  That said, it is changing...can you show what SaveData does?  Also try just storing the DateTime.Now without helping with a format - you might be confusing it

Comment: Please check updated question... I have added the query which generates while saving...

Comment: you are explicitly setting it to `'1/6/2016 20:28:31'` which is text, not a date time type by the way and not the value of `RedeemedDate`  that value will refer to June 1 if your culture is dd/mm like the UK

Comment: Remove the .`ToString(...`

Comment: checked , still have the same issue...and I have US date time settings on my machine...

Comment: checked *what*?  Just pass it `DateTime.Now` and store that value not an explicit string value

Comment: yes...I have just set to System.DateTime.Now , still saves as a 1-June-2016

Comment: did you change the update statement - it is not even using what is in `RedeemedDate` but an explicit string value

Comment: RedeemedDate have datetime column... its working fine till 31-Dec-2015... Its showing error since new year...

Comment: Are you even reading these?  Your SQL **does not** use the value of RedeemedDate:  `UPDATE Coupon SET CouponNo ... ,RedeemedDate = '1/6/2016 20:28:31',`

Comment: What changes I have suppose to do in Query... ?

Comment: please show SaveData in its entirety.

Comment: Oh wait...Its happening in every entity... Every date stamp saving as 1-Jun-2016.... It will be nice if you come to the chat...

Comment: Of course it is! Go back and read all the comments carefully.  I shant repeat myself again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99952/discussion-between-user1650894-and-plutonix).

Comment: Last chance: **please paste the code for the `Coupon.Save` method**

Comment: down vote - not describing the data layer

Comment: ok, since that calls `Update()` please show that @rheitzman - yes, that why I want to see the saving stuff

Comment: @ rheitzman Please wait I am updating the question... Please dont hurry in down voting... the code passes different layers.. let me check how many functions I can add here...

Comment: "hurry"??? this has been going on for an hour.  I cant even tell if you are reading anything

Comment: Please check the updated question...

Comment: Please check question now, this may give you clear picture of how data transfers...

Comment: are you using EF or something like that?

Comment: No, Not at all, I'm not using entity framework...

Comment: like @rheitzman, I still dont know what data access provider you are using.  whatever it is that generates that SQL (you still havent said), it is wrong.  Treating it as string allows culture issues to creep in, which is what the core problem is.  1/6 is Jan 6 US, but June 1 euro/uk

Comment: I don't think it can give any idea...I have update the code with SetColumn code as well.. i am not putting entire code because I t might create confustion...please check the update question...

Comment: Where did you get this DB mechanism?  Since everything gets passed As Object, when you pass a string, the data now looks like a string and/or the SQL generator is ultimately confused because your column mechanism is not saving the datatype (and we ***still*** dont know the data provider!)

Comment: Well, thats main problem... previously I am using the same code from SQL SERVER 2000. Now I am using the code from MS ACCESS, since once year, its working fine... Thats why I am also confused...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and support and valuable time... I will check all the code again...

Comment: This is most likely a localization issue. The date string passed to Access should be yyyy\mm\dd. Looking at your date table you can see that your day is being converted to a month.

Comment: Ya,I have to check again...But I am still wondering how its working whole year ???

Answer (score 0):

You failed to indicate what data layer you are using (ADO, ADO.Net - OleDB), and I suspect you are using VBA in Access and not VB.Net (Visual Studio.)

That said, an access update would look like this:

```
UPDATE a SET a.dt = #2016/3/2#;
```

The #'s delimit date strings. the yyyy/m/d format avoids localization issues.

Comment: A tag is vb.net is should probably be vba (Access VBA). Depends on what the IDE is.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for detecting the problem,It will be nice if you tell me what exactly change I have to made while writing the code...what the query should look like ?Im wondering how it saving the correct date so far... ?

Comment: we dont even know what you are programming in!  Is it VB.NET as tagged using Visual Studio or is this an Access thing?

Comment: Ok, so your question says `Its generates following query...` *what* generates it?  Please show that entire method...if it really is Visual Studio

Comment: No.  I do not do chat.  This is a QA site.  We want code, not pictures of code

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your SetColumn function:

```
SetColumn(RedeemedDateColumnName, _RedeemedDate)
```

It generates:

```
RedeemedDate = '1/6/2016 20:28:31'
```

while it - for Access - should create:

```
RedeemedDate = #1/6/2016 20:28:31#
```

Comment: OK , but since year it working fine... It showing problem since New year...I haven't made any changes to DateTime on My PC...

Comment: @ user1650894 The date 1st June 2016 is 01-06-2016 - today is 06-01-16 I suspect that it's your date  formatting that is different to the date formatting in the access data. Tomorrow all your dates will show as 1st July 2016.